# jQuery parser error ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying .ajax to hit a URL which returns a list of object, I am using jacksonJsonView in spring to it returns json in browser. But when I try this code it never goes into the success, but the error alert shows the textstatus to be 'parseerror'. the alert looks like this: 'status=parsererror,error=jQuery15109695890768120119_1357924928198 was not called'

```
$(function() {  
$("#tags").autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8181/jquery/api/states/regex?stateName='+request.term,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
        alert("test");

        },
        error: function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
})
```

The API returns some thing like this:

```
[

    {
        "id": 12,
        "stateName": "Vermont",
        "intPtLon": -72.673354,
        "intPtLat": 44.0605475,
        "stUsps": "VT"
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "stateName": "Virginia",
        "intPtLon": -78.6681938,
        "intPtLat": 37.5222512,
        "stUsps": "VA"
    }

]
```

Adding the following line fixed the issue, it works fine in IE bit not so much in firefox

Comment: Are you sure you need a JSONP?

Comment: If I remove it, it gives  "status=error,error="

Comment: See my answer. Suppose changing `dataType: 'jsonp',` to `dataType: 'json',` will be completely enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

to simple

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Or, if you really need JSONP and can't use JSON - you should take callback parameter from request on server side and wrap response like this:

Request["callback"] + "(" + string_with_json_response + ")";

So, in results you will get something like:

```
jQuery15109695890768120119_1357924928198('{"response":"val"}');
```

Comment: Changing jsonp to json gives me "Status=error,error=". and where do I add the Request["callback"] + "(" + string_with_json_response + ")"; ?

Comment: Hm. That is strange. Response you shown in your question looks like valid JSON. Take a look at network tab of developer tools in browser. You should find your ajax request there after it is executed and take response from there. Response you provided looks to be Ok and it should work fine with `dataType":'json'`. About where to add - I can give only direction. It should be at the same place where current response is returned. Not sure how you do that in Java.

Comment: everything looks fine in firebug/net, The response header looks like this Content-Type application/json
Server Jetty(6.1.22)
Transfer-Encoding chunked

Comment: Does the [] around the json matter? not sure how to remove it. in some posts they suggest that it could be the issue

Comment: Hm. That should not be a problem at all. That is a valid JSON array. Have you checked plain response text? Possibly you have some garbage there which you do not see, but it breaks jQuery

Comment: Actually I got the success function working by adding this : jQuery.support.cors = true;

Comment: Hm. Is your request passed to the same server where general page is located? So, in other words, does your page have an url like http://localhost:8181/some_page?

Comment: If you are doing request to the same server, than you just need to fix your ajax request URL to avoid problems with Cross-Domain Requests

Comment: my jquery page is on xampp while the api is on jetty, so that could be the issue Thanks for your help